Problems connecting to local mosquitto mqtt broker with Android Studio
I tried to connect my local mosquitto mqtt broker to Android Studio to be able to receive data which is sent from an esp32 via mqtt, but I always get an system error.
I have mosquitto running locally and that works fine, but when i try to connect to the broker from Android Studio i always get a system error.
This is my code:
package com.example.pulsapp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String BROKER_URL = "tcp://192.168.178.48:1883";
private static final String CLIENT_ID = "xxx";
private static final String topic = "test";
private MqttHandler mqttHandler;
private Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mqttHandler = new MqttHandler();
    mqttHandler.connect(BROKER_URL,CLIENT_ID);
    init();

}

private void init() {
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_sub);
    //client = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), MQTT_BROKER_URL, clientID);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            subscribeToTopic("test");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mqttHandler.disconnect();
    super.onDestroy();

}
private void publishMessage(String topic, String message){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Publishing message: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mqttHandler.publish(topic,message);
}
private void subscribeToTopic(String topic){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Subscribing to topic "+ topic, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mqttHandler.subscribe(topic);
}
}

And this is the error I get:
2024-06-15 12:38:56.015 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W  Client is not connected (32104)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.015 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at  org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.016 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms.sendNoWait(ClientComms.java:205)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.017 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.subscribeBase(MqttAsyncClient.java:1088)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.018 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.subscribe(MqttAsyncClient.java:1152)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.019 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:459)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.019 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:429)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.019 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:404)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.019 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at com.example.pulsapp.MqttHandler.subscribe(MqttHandler.java:50)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.020 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at com.example.pulsapp.MainActivity.subscribeToTopic(MainActivity.java:54)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.020 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at com.example.pulsapp.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:13)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.020 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at com.example.pulsapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.021 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7659)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.021 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1218)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.021 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7636)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.022 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.023 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30156)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.023 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.023 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.024 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.024 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.025 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.025 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.026 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
2024-06-15 12:38:56.027 11861-11861 System.err              com.example.pulsapp                  W      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)


What do the mosquitto logs show, and is there also a "CausedBy" exception after the one you've listed?
